# HAProxy + docker (HTTPS->HTTP) 503 Service Unavailable (secured with a certificate)

Tags: docker, nginx, haproxy

Please help. I was stuck on it for the fourth day, tested dozens of configurations and parameter combinations (mainly in haproxy.cfg) and I don't have the strength or ideas what I'm doing wrong. This is my start with haproxy and I guess I'm making some simple mistake.
My goal is to configure the environment in such a way that the main web application running natively on the virtual machine port 8050 and application 1, application 2 etc. (web applications launched in the docker environment over the http protocol) were available from the Internet at public domain addresses secured with the HTTPS protocol.

Below are my configuration files and an overview diagram of the environment. Certbot works, I have obtained the certificate, all applications run over the http protocol using DNS names. Whenever I use https: // I get 503 service unavailable (but secured with a certificate).
I am asking for any help or hint.

haproxy: 2.6.2

[image: 1]

```
server {
        listen       8050 default_server;
        listen       [::]:8050 default_server;

        root /usr/share/nginx/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Limit File Upload Size in Nginx
        client_max_body_size 1024M;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index            index.php;
                fastcgi_pass             php-fpm;
        # (or 127.0.0.1:9000)
                include                  fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }


HAProxy



    global
        daemon
    
        # Enable HAProxy runtime API
        stats socket :9999 level admin expose-fd listeners
    
    defaults
        mode    http
        timeout connect 5000ms
        timeout client 50000ms
        timeout server 50000ms
        timeout http-request 10000ms
        option http-keep-alive
        option log-health-checks
        log global
    
    # HTTP
    frontend http-in
        bind :80
    
        # Forward HTTPS
    #    http-request redirect scheme https code 301 unless { ssl_fc }
    #    http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }
    
        # Certbot
        acl certbot path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
        use_backend certbot_be if certbot
    
        # Website 1 example.com
    #    redirect scheme http if { hdr(Host) -i example.com } { ssl_fc }
        acl host_example.com hdr(host) -i example.com
        use_backend web-example.com_be if host_example.com
    
        # Website 2 phppgadmin.example.com
        acl host_phppgadmin hdr(host) -i phppgadmin.example.com
        use_backend web-phppgadmin_be if host_phppgadmin
    
        # Website 3 portainer.example.com
        acl host_portainer hdr(host) -i portainer.example.com
        use_backend web-portainer_be if host_portainer
    
        default_backend web-example.com_be
    
    
    # HTTPS
    frontend https-in
        bind :443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/certificates/
        http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    
        # Certbot
        acl certbot path_beg /.well-known/acme-challenge/
        use_backend certbot_be if certbot
    
        # Docker resolver
        resolvers docker
        nameserver dns1 127.0.0.11:53
    
    
    # Certbot backend
    backend certbot_be
        server xxx.lan.example.com certbot:380
    
    backend web-example.com_be
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
        http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
        server xxx.lan.example.com 10.10.10.114:8050 ssl verify none
    
    backend web-phppgadmin_be
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
        http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
        server xxx.lan.example.com phppgadmin:8001
    
    backend web-portainer_be
        http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
        http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
        server xxx.lan.example.com portainer:8002
```

Comment: 2 things look odd: 1. your `frontend https-in` doesn't have default backend. 2. your `backend web-example.com_be` declares `ssl` on the server line, but it seems to me you it should be without ssl

Comment: ad1 added ad2 deleted  now gets working in part 

"This site has a valid certificate, issued by a trusted authority.

However, some parts of the site are not secure. This means information (such as passwords or credit cards) might not be securely sent to this site and may be intercepted or seen by others."

Comment: e.g. on main app some elements are missing like css (syles);

Comment: @tbielaszewski Thank you so much. This helped me a lot. 2nd Problem with "parts not secure" was on app settings/config site: solution here: https://eduroll.eu/installing-moodle-using-ssl-proxy/

Raz jeszcze dziękuję. Masz u mnie piwo :)